# Bash file exists test via string vs array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, sh

I'm trying to understand why using an array value won't detect a file's existence.

I have loaded a file path into the array. When I reference the array position, the value is correct.  When I use that exact string as the test input it detects the file.  However, when I instead use the array position as the test input it does not detect the file.

```
echo "${mycsv[0]}"
  # output: 0/0/0/1/000134329.bz

if test -f "0/0/0/1/000134329.bz"
then echo "exists"
else echo "not exists"
fi
  # output: exists
 
if test -f "${mycsv[0]}"
then echo "exists"
else echo "not exists"
fi
  # output: not exists
```

Comment: My guess is there's extra whitespace characters in the array element.

Comment: Try `echo "|${mycsv[0]}|"`

Comment: If you loaded the array from a file, it may have CRLF line breaks instead of just LF, and the CR character is in the array element.

Comment: All above are good points. Regarding CRLF, use `cat -vet myDatafile | head -10` and if  you see `^M$` at the end of each line, the `dos2unix myDatafile` will fix it. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, @Barmar that's exactly what the problem was. There was CRLF in the one that was failing.  Cleaning up the input file fixed the problem!  Thank you!